# Why once wrap typedef function signature doesn't match the original signature

Tags: c++, function, type-conversion

Why does this code print 1 then 0 ?

```
typedef void (* GLFWkeyfun)(GLFWwindow*,int,int,int,int);
std::cout << std::is_same<GLFWkeyfun, void(*)(GLFWwindow*, int, int, int, int)>::value << std::endl;
std::cout << std::is_same<std::function<GLFWkeyfun>, std::function<void(GLFWwindow*, int, int, int, int)>>::value << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `GLFWkeyfun` is a function *pointer* type. Instead, the function type is specified as the `std::function`'s template argument in `std::function<void(GLFWwindow*, int, int, int, int)>`.

We should specify function type to `std::function`. You can apply [`std::remove_pointer`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer) on `GLFWkeyfun`, e.g.

```
std::cout << std::is_same<std::function<std::remove_pointer_t<GLFWkeyfun>>,
//                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^          ^ 
                          std::function<void(GLFWwindow*, int, int, int, int)>>::value
          << std::endl;
```

If your compiler doesn't support C++14, then

```
std::cout << std::is_same<std::function<std::remove_pointer<GLFWkeyfun>::type>,
//                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^          ^^^^^^^
                          std::function<void(GLFWwindow*, int, int, int, int)>>::value
          << std::endl;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe5516701d04d391)

Comment: It's always enlighting. I made an [MCVE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe5516701d04d391) on coliru.

Comment: Alternatively, changing to `using GLFWkeyfun = void(GLFWwindow*,int,int,int,int);` (no longer pointer) and use the appropriate type between `GLFWkeyfun*` and `GLFWkeyfun`. (less verbose to add pointer than remove it).

Comment: @Jarod42 Good general advice, but I think the `GLFW` prefix suggests that in this case, the typedef is not under the OP's control.

Comment: Thank you :) I understand better now.
I'm just sad that I cannot convert my lambda to a function pointer because of my captures :(